# is it possible to run virtualbox inside a docker container

Tags: virtualbox, docker

I tried running the container in privileged mode, but still the vboxdrv cannot be loaded.

I get

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
     available for the current kernel (3.11.0-22-generic) or it failed to
     load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

       sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

Comment: Did you install the kernel module on your host system ?

Comment: I did. Still the same error.

Comment: Can you give us more info about : your system, your docker version, how you're launching vbox into a container ?

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you can. You'll need to make sure you have the kernel module on your host system. I'm running Ubuntu, but I'm sure it'd be similar on other distros:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic virtualbox-dkms
```

And make sure the kernel module is loaded:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/virtualbox status
VirtualBox kernel modules are loaded.
```

Now, run the docker container, and mount /dev/vboxdrv as a volume:

```
docker run -it -v /dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv your/container-image
```

Comment: are you sure this is `-v` rather than `--device` (device)? I get `Failed to open "/dev/vboxdrvu", errno=1, rc=VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_ACCESSIBLE`. Also, under privileged mode my Windows box just uses 100% CPU and never does anything, but I think that's a different problem.

Comment: On RHEL, 


sudo dnf -y install dkms kernel-devel

Answer (score 12):

Edited at `2016-03-27 12:54 UTC`

I have the exact same issue and I can successfully dockerize the latest version of VirtualBox with the Extension Pack and phpvirtualbox on CentOS 7.

You have to install tons of dependencies such as kernel-devel, make, gcc and dkms. After finishing the docker build, <strike>you MUST run the docker image with these flags `--privileged=true -v /dev/:/dev/`.</strike> you need the flag `--privileged=true` to run the image with the docker version of 1.10.3

<strike>For the details, please see my [`Dockerfile`](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/wood1986/docker-phpvirtualbox/dockerfile/) and [`run.sh`](https://github.com/wood1986/docker-phpvirtualbox/blob/master/run.sh)</strike>

For the details, please have a look [my repository](https://github.com/wood1986/docker-library/tree/master/virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.phpvirtualbox) especially [`Makefile`](https://github.com/wood1986/docker-library/blob/master/virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.phpvirtualbox/Makefile), [`virtualbox.Dockerfile`](https://github.com/wood1986/docker-library/blob/master/virtualbox/Dockerfile), [`vboxwebsrv.Dockerfile`](https://github.com/wood1986/docker-library/blob/master/vboxwebsrv/Dockerfile) and [`phpvirtualbox.Dockerfile`](https://github.com/wood1986/docker-library/blob/master/phpvirtualbox/Dockerfile)

Comment: do you need `-v` if you specify `--privileged=true`? I thought it was implied.

Comment: yes, still need. it will have an error when running `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` inside the container.`Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                         [FAILED]
  (Cannot create device /dev/vboxdrv with major 10 and minor  57u
 58)`

Comment: it's definitely not needed anymore with more recent docker/virtualbox. The device is passed correctly with `--device`

Comment: btw you absolutely shouldn't be running `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv` inside the guest! That's for installing the kernel module, which is what the host needs to do.

Comment: Thanks fommil!! It's time for me to clean up the script

Comment: I've spent the last two weeks trying to get this to work, I've finally got my CI working with Linux / Windows cross builds but had to eventually give up because my CI box is a KVM VPS and, unfortunately, virtualbox does not run very efficiently under KVM.

Comment: Your findings will be correct if you are not the first time to run the container.          At the first time of running the container with the flag `--privileged -v /dev/:/dev/` and `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`, this will create `/dev/vboxdrv` on the host. Once you stop the container, `/dev/vboxdrv` still exists on the host. So you can just run the container with the flag `--device=[/dev/vboxdrv]` at the second time.          /etc/init.d/vboxdrv is not run inside the **VM Guest** and it is run inside the **Docker Containter**. Otherwise, you wont be able to run VirtualBox inside the container.

Comment: you can just run that script on the host and then there is no need to do anything in the guest (what you're clarifying as the docker container). In fact, I think it's probably unstable to be installing guest kernel modules into the host.

Comment: I try to install and run VM in a container and commands (vboxmanage) work but after not list VM as running and not show process of VM with ps

Comment: With virtualbox 5.2 I have to run `apt-get install kmod` inside docker image as well, otherwise virtualbox will try to use lsmod but could not find the command, and errors.

Answer (score 7):

**2019:**

- Virtualbox version: 6.0
- Docker version: 18.09.6
- Ubuntu 18.04

The key is to use a docker image that has systemd running. I chose `jrei/systemd-ubuntu` see [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrei/systemd-ubuntu).

```
    docker run -d --privileged \
    --name systemd-ubuntu --network=host \
    --device /dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv \
    -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
    -v /tmp:/tmp -it jrei/systemd-ubuntu
```

Inside the container I ran:

```
    apt update
    apt -y install wget
    apt -y install gnupg2
    apt -y install systemd
    apt -y install software-properties-common
    wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | apt-key add -
    wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | apt-key add -
    add-apt-repository "deb https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib"
    apt update
    apt -y install virtualbox-6.0
```

Enjoy :-)

Comment: i got this when trying to install using your method when running VBoxManage ```WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.15.0-1032-gcp) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig```

Answer (score 4):

**2021:**

Check [my git repository](https://github.com/ngaro/docker-virtualbox) to see how i did it with VirtualBox 6.1 based on Ubuntu 20.04.

Just running: `docker run -d --rm --network=host --device /dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv -e DISPLAY=unix:0 garo/docker-virtualbox` will do the trick.

Don't forget, as mentioned in the other replies, you will need to have the virtualbox kernel modules on your host system. Installing VirtualBox on the host is the easiest way to do this. (You can remove it again immediately after the installation)