# Why is virtualbox running so slowly under docker?

Tags: docker, virtualbox

I'm trying to get virtualbox to run inside docker. I'm well past [is it possible to run virtualbox inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741904) because I can start VBoxManage but it unfortunately spins at 100% CPU (despite working perfectly on the host) for several minutes before finally settling.

This is the Dockerfile I'm running: https://github.com/fommil/freeslick/tree/docker-build which includes a Windows XP virtualbox image built using these instructions https://github.com/fommil/freeslick/tree/docker-base

My host has the dkms running (and virtualbox/that image works), and I'm starting the container under privileged mode (to keep things simple):

```
docker run -i -t --privileged=true fommil/freeslick:build
```

But when I start a headless VM with

```
VBoxManage startvm --type headless MSSQL
```

(which works when run just on the host) VBox just consumes 100% and the services I expect sometimes never start up (I'm trying to get connections to MSSQL via `tsql`, see the `await-mssql.sh` script at the same repo).

To keep things nice and simple, my host and container are both running Debian Jessie (although I eventually want to run Jessie on an externally hosted Ubuntu VPS... let's leave that for another day)

Is there something additional that I need to do in order to be able to run virtualbox under docker?

There is nothing untoward in the log files when run inside the container, except perhaps this (almost 3 minutes to do command 0x30)

```
00:00:03.176907 Guest Log: BIOS: Booting from Hard Disk...
00:02:48.776941 PIIX3 ATA: execution time for ATA command 0x30 was 164 seconds
```

there is no such 0x30 command when running on the host.

**UPDATE** [ATA command 0x30 is WRITE SECTORS](http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode#Writing_28_bit_LBA). I wonder if docker is doing a "copy on write" for my 6GB windows drive, simply as part of the Windows bootup process. Hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering my own question: it really was the copy-on-write behaviour. My VPS has really slow hard drives that get even slower under docker. Workaround is to try to use a faster volume for my images and create fresh copies in that space before starting the image.