# Virtualbox inside docker container without host dependency

Tags: docker, virtualbox

I researched about how to use the VirtualBox inside a container without any dependency of the host machine.

The bad thing is that I need to share some drivers from the host to the container.

I would like to have the VirtualBox running inside the container and not worry about the OS of the host.

**Has anyone managed to do this?**

[This is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741904/is-it-possible-to-run-virtualbox-inside-a-docker-container/26916408#26916408) related to this.

Comment: A docker container is not a virtual machine- it is a way of running a process on the host machine with a private file system and a reduced namespace.  Virtualization is extremely host dependent- usually requiring actual hardware support to be enabled, and always requiring kernel support... and Docker uses the host hardware and kernel.

Comment: I understand your point. I'm creating Vagrant boxes using `docker-machine create` append some stuff, create the box `vagrant package` and then delete the machine.  just I use it only to create boxes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to run virtualbox inside a docker container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741904/is-it-possible-to-run-virtualbox-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: It makes sense to use your container to pack up the software and scripts to interact with Virtualbox, but the nature of the platform makes it impossible to remove the dependency on the host OS.

Comment: @PaulBecotte Even If I decided to install tons of dependencies in the container? I don't know if that will be possible.

Comment: virtualbox requires kernel modules- the container has no kernel.